# Как мне присваивать уникальный id для посетителей сайта?

Tags: php, mysql, cookie, веб-программирование, аналитика

Всем привет!
Суть задачи такова:
нужно сделать индетификатор пользователя как например у Google Analytics и присваивать ему определенные результаты
заходит посетитель на сайт первый раз ему должен записываться в куки и в БД уникальный id, для того что бы потом идентифицировать юзера, (и в следующем его посещении не писать id) но вот если юзер почистил куки или сменил браузер, как тогда определить посещал раньше юзер сайт или нет?
 и если посещал то использовать уже записанный в БД уникальный id, а если нет то создать ему уникальный id и записать в БД при этом id не должны повторятся
или сверять ip за сутки?

Comment: Без дополнительных манипуляций(регистрации) - никак

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич а если писать такие данные как Страна, ip, и ещё что то, что бы потом можно было сравнить?? меня интересует сама реализация, идеально конечно было бы использовать mac адрес машины, но вот гугл ответил что это не реально

Comment: IP у многих, например, у меня, динамический, то есть разный после каждой перезагрузки модема, сегодня этот IP  у меня, завтра он может быть у кого-то в другом р-не города, ну а страна, регион, они ничего Вам не дадут

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич мне это нужно для логов, хочу присвоить id юзеру на сайте а потом когда он перейдет из приложения то что бы не создавать нового юзера а использовать существующего

Comment: Ну, это вы точно без введения данных от пользователя не сделаете, он ведь даже с другого устройства, скорее всего, заходить будет, тут только создание аккаунта пользователем и потом введение им своих данных в приложении

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич важен только компьютер, нужно сделать индетификатор пользователя как например у Google Analytics и присваивать ему определенные результаты

Answer (score 1):

в целом - это невозможно.

проблема в том, что для идентификации пользователя без регистрации - это все "вилами по воде", человек должен ввести пароль для логина. пароль + логин должны быть уникальными.

если вы делаете рекламную систему, то вам не важен и не нужен логин пользователя (да его у вас и нет), вам главное угадать пользователя (и это все, что вы можете сделать - угадать)

вы можете отделить пользователей от пользователей с помощью целой кучи параметров браузера:

- кука (в которой можно накопить дофига инфы)
- айпи
- плагины в браузере
- шрифты

(MAC вы не достанете  и MAC не уникален)

короче, регистрация или догадки.

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически, можно запомнить не конкретного пользователя, как написали выше, а группу пользователей сходных по своим характеристикам. Возможно, для ваших целей, этого будет достаточно.

Для этого, формируем id из всех доступных нам характеристик: местоположение, версия браузера, ip адрес. При этом ip адреса нужно разбивать по группам, соответствующим определенным провайдерам, и считать ip адрес конкретного пользователя равным id группы.

Для некоторых специфических сайтов, как например для форума, можно так же использовать группу топиков, которые посетил пользователь, полностью идентифицированный как один в относительно короткий промежуток времени, с его более ранними визитами в другие дни. Это может добавить какие-то проценты к точности.

Я, кстати, почти уверен, что крупные корпорации научились весьма точно идентифицировать пользователей, так что не согласен, что эту задачу невозможно решить, да сложно, но когда-то было невозможным общаться с миллионом людей одновременно посредством этого сообщения, так что слово "невозможно" - очень далеко от реальности. Да, сложно. Да, на данный момент в открытых источниках тяжело найти информацию о том, как это сделать; но точно НЕ невозможно.

Comment: пользователя _невозможно_ идентифицировать без логина/пароля, и да, это печально для реклов

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что именно невозможно, возможно добиться более-менее высокой точности, но не точно определить пользователя, банально, одним устройством могут пользоваться 2-3 разных человека, которым нужны разные параметры и интересен разный контент

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич вы сами только что подсказали путь, как можно этих пользователей, пользующихся одним устройством, различить. Так что все проблемы решаются.

Comment: @Razzwan в смысле, не совсем понял, как я подсказал?)

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич разные пользователи заходят на разные сайты. Соответственно, по этому признаку их можно различить.